# How can I tell what time a web site stopped in IIS 8.5

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

For some unknown reason one of my sites stopped on the server.

I have looked in the the Application and System event logs, as well as the logs located at: C:\inetpub\logs. However I see no indication of when the a site was stopped or why.

I used to be able to find this info in the eventlogs in IIS 6, but am stumped as where to look now.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no specific log for start and stop events for sites in IIS 7+

If you have a site with constant traffic to it, you can use the regular http logs to see when a site was restarted or recycled. Find the headers:

```
2015-05-15 05:34:46 ::1 GET /
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2015-05-15 05:34:54
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method
```

if this case you can see the last request before the restart at `05:34:46` and the start of the site at `05:34:54`

Of course this doesn't tell you why the site was stopped, check the recycle settings of the application pool and your error logs.

Comment: Its happened twice in the last three weeks on two different servers, and just seems odd. I have seen app pools stopped due to issues/errors, but I had never had a site stop like this.